# Expansion of polytabloids in the standard basis

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

would like to know the most efficient way to write a polytabloid in terms of standard ones.

I know the Garnir elements, but using them to do calculations is hard. I also read about "quadratic elements" in Fulton's Young Tableaux, but I hope a better construction exists.

The thing I would like to have is, in a perfect world, an algorithm that has a random polytabloid and a standard one as input, and the coefficient of the standard polytabloid in the expansion of the random polytabloid as an output. I don't think such algorithm exists, but it can help figure out what kind of algorithm I am looking for.

Comment: Are you asking for a straightening rule? A recent preprint claims to give an explicit one: [Reuven Hodges, *A closed non-iterative formula for straightening fillings of Young diagrams*, arXiv:1710.05214v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.05214v1).